# wp nav menu items wrap not working

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Having an issue with the arguments for wp_nav_menu, currently I have this very simple code:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Header Menu', 'container' => '', 'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="nav nav-navbar %2$s">%3$s</ul>' )); ?>
```

Whatever I do the UL stays completely blank, no id or class is being outputted.

Strange thing is I have this exact code running on another install, and the items_wrap output there works absolutely fine. I've tried numerous things, but ul stays blank. Container/menu class works fine but are not necessary.

Latest WordPress downloaded today from wordpress.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jamie, I think you might have forgoten to [create a menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_SubPanel) called "Header Menu".

Comment: Thanks for the comment I do believe I made a header menu, but will double check into that might be slightly different named

Edit: your correct, although I did create it in the functions, I still had to create it in the appearance->menus section. Thanks!